# Access VBA: run function after changing data

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have a subform within a form.
In this subform I enter line per line the mail-addresses of customers.

I want to set a mailstring like this into the parent form of the subform.
Example in Subform:

```
mail1@test.com
mail2@test.com
mail3@anothertest.com
```

whenever I leave the field "mail" on subform a string such as 
mail1@test.com; mail2@test.com; mail3@anothertest.com
should be put into field "Parentmail" on mainform.

It is not the problem to `CREATE` the mailstring (3 mailaddresses) but on WHICH EVENT on the subform (or field on subform) can I run the function??

I tried

```
 Form_AfterUpdate
```

(subform !) but it only works when I add new mail-addresses or when I update an existing one, not when I delete one.

Which event will fire when I have maybe 3 mail-addresses and delete one?

```
  Form_Delete
```

did not do the job.

Thx Michael

Comment: You can try to set a timer in Form_Delete, see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39649299/3820271 -- Or build the mailstring when it is actually needed (when sending the mail), not before.

Comment: As @Andre said, no need to save this concatenated value and really shouldn't. Calculate the concatenation when needed. If each email address is a record, review http://allenbrowne.com/func-concat.html

Comment: Thx. Yes, I will follow that as there are few other reasons Ro do so. Michael

Answer (score 0):

Try the subform BeforeDelConfirm event: `Replace(mainformfield, subformfield & ";", "")`.